# Debug information with UDF's in Hive

Tags: java, hive

I'm trying to get GeoIP working with hive. I found this: http://www.jointhegrid.com/hive-udf-geo-ip-jtg/index.jsp, which seems to be exactly what I want.

I built the jars (I have no java experience, so I only hope I did this part right), added them to my query and get this:

```
hive> ADD jar hive-udf-geo-ip-jtg.jar;
Added hive-udf-geo-ip-jtg.jar to class path
Added resource: hive-udf-geo-ip-jtg.jar
hive> ADD jar geo-ip-java.jar;
Added geo-ip-java.jar to class path
Added resource: geo-ip-java.jar
hive> ADD file GeoIPCity.dat;
Added resource: GeoIPCity.dat
hive> create temporary function geoip as 'com.jointhegrid.hive.udf.GenericUDFGeoIP';
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionTask
```

Is there a way to find out what exactly is going wrong? `return code 1` doesn't tell me much... Is there a log file somewhere?

Comment: If you go to the job tracker each task inside of a job has a log file.

Comment: Thanks @Steve, I forgot about the drill-down!  Just found my UDF bug way down in the syslog of a task attempt (was expecting it to show up in the stderr of the failed step).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you want to see the log of hive, you can use `$HIVE_HOME/bin/hive -hiveconf hive.root.logger=INFO,console`. You can also change levels (DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR or FATAL) to see if you can get enough information.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing hive UDF with below command

```
hive --hiveconf hive.root.logger=DRFA --hiveconf hive.log.dir=./logs --hiveconf hive.log.level=DEBUG -e "query"

or

hive --hiveconf hive.root.logger=DRFA --hiveconf hive.log.dir=./logs --hiveconf hive.log.level=DEBUG -f queryscript.hql
```

The logs would be captured in a file under logs folder (current directory). Please make sure that the logs folder exist.

Try adjusting log level to get right detail.